# Get Images from Request in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**I have the following data in request.data**

```
<QueryDict: {'eventID': ['1'], 'image_0': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Bohr.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'image_1': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: ptcl.png (image/png)>], 'image_2': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: PTCL.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'image_3': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: ptcll.png (image/png)>]}>
```

This is my code which I am using to get the values but it works only there is only one value of an image.

```
def AddGallery(request):
status={'ErrorCode':-1,'ErrorMsg':'Initial-request Add images'}

context = {}
try:

    print (request.data)

    event = request.data.get('eventID', None)
    image = request.data.get('image', None)


    usr_mgmt =UserAuthenticationA()
    status = usr_mgmt.AddGallery(event, image)
except Exception as e:
    print (str(e))
context.update(status)
return Response(context)
```

I need the solution with which I can extract the multiple images.